# How to disable all links of a particular GPO with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gpo

The task I need to perform is to disable all links of given GPOs.
I get all GPOs with:

```
$GPOs = Get-GPO -All |select DisplayName,id
```

But below is not working:

```
Set-GPLink -Guid $GPOs[0].id.guid -Target * -LinkEnabled No
```

I think the problem is with the "*".
Can you help me with a PowerShell command for that, please?

Comment: the `-Target` parameter of `Set-GPLink` expects a path to the linked OU (distinguished name). You have to get all current links and iterate with a foreach loop to remove each link individually. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/set-gplink?view=windowsserver2022-ps